# Mongodb php aggregation

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

i would like to know how to make aggregation based on my display.php.
My aggregation in mongodb:

```
db.data.aggregate(
    { $match : { name : "test1" } }
);
```

Display is realized in this way:

```
<?php  
// Config  
$dbhost = 'localhost';  
$dbname = 'users';  

// Connect to test database  
$m = new Mongo("mongodb://$dbhost");  
$db = $m->$dbname;  

// select the collection  
$collection = $db->dane;  

  $criteria = array(
    'name' => 'login',
  );

// pull a cursor query  
$cursor = $collection->find($criteria);  
   echo $cursor->count() . ' document(s) found. <br/>';  
  foreach ($cursor as $obj) {
    echo 'id: ' . $obj['_id'] . '<br/>';
    echo 'nick: ' . $obj['name'] . '<br/>';
    echo 'description: ' . $obj['description'] . '<br/>';
    echo 'link: ' . $obj['link'] . '<br/>';
    echo 'old_link: ' . $obj['old_link'] . '<br/>';
    echo '<br/>';
  }
  $m->close();
?>
```

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: What do you mean based on display? Showing us just your code isn't going to help much

Comment: I just want to display _ids from my collection by using aggregate but i cant display _id like this.

<?php
// Config  
$dbhost = 'localhost';  
$dbname = 'users';  
  
// Connect to test database  
$m = new Mongo("mongodb://$dbhost");  
$db = $m->$dbname;  
  
// select the collection  
$collection = $db->dane;  
  
  $cursor = $collection->aggregate(
  array ('$match' => array('nick' => 'test1')
        )
    
);
 echo count($cursor);
 echo $cursor['_id'] ;      <---

?>

Comment: it would be `$cursor['result'][0]['_id']` but why do you need aggregate for that?

Comment: Definitely no need for Aggregation Framework if you just want to display a list of `_ids`. You can use a normal `find()` query with projection.